# Xcode 7.3: Can't debug with assembly language

Tags: assembly, xcode7, xcode7.3

I just started to program in Xcode today, and I'm trying to debug a program in NASM assembly language.(The project is external build system)

The options in debug are grey. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you load and run the program ?

Comment: @Pierre I am also interested in what you mean as I want to do the same: Use XCode debugger front end to debug external build of NASM assembly code.

Comment: @Pierre Yes, I did. It was built successfully. But I didn't set any outputs. Does that matter?

Comment: Stella -Have you found a solution?